# How do I change my function so that the entire header can be parsed into the new file?

Tags: c, ppm

So I created a function is able to pull the header from a file and put it into a new file without the comments. All the .ppm files have a max color value of 255 so here is my function:

```
void headerinfo(FILE *infile, FILE *outfile){

    char line[100];
    int c;

    fgets(line,100,infile);
    c=strlen(line);

    while(line[c]!='\n' && line[c-1]!='5' && line[c-2]!='5' && line[c-3]!='2'){
            if(line[0]=='#'){
                    fgets(line,100,infile);
                    c=strlen(line);
            }
            else{
                    fputs(line,outfile);
                    fgets(line,100,infile);
                    c=strlen(line);
                 }
        }
        fputs(line,outfile);
}
```

The issue I am running into is that I have two .ppm files with similar header formats, but the one with 561 by 375 dimensions does not output the last line with 255 onto the new file. Is there a difference between these two files that is affected by my code?

[Here is the .ppm file that does not copy over the 255 line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTjSR.jpg)

[Here is the .ppm file that does copy the 255 line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFCyK.jpg)

[.ppm file that works](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T9zLSt5YKJinacwpvGKqaDtg-PmXYO5U/view?usp=sharing)

[.ppm file that does not work](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jh-6EFbAtgk1NKBT7HeOkQuM7QKbVYxO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you github (or otherwise) provide the actual files to evaluate.  Without them it may be difficult to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: added the .ppm files

Comment: @EricPostpischil - I do not doubt for a second that you somehow know this from looking at the images, but _how_ do you know it?  (or is it the test for `\n` in the code that allows you to draw the conclusion.)

Comment: @ryyker: Link to download the files were added to the question. I downloaded them and dumped their contents with the Unix command `od`.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` conditions are wrong. Since `c` is the length of the string, `line[c]` points to the null character that ends it. It can never be `'\n'`. And `line[c-1]` is the `'\n'` that ends a line (except possibly for the last line in a file), so it is never `'5'` (unless the last line ends with `'5'`). And of course `line[c-2]` and `line[c-3]` are also out of position.

What you actually want is:

```
while (! (4 <= c && line[c-4] == '2' && line[c-3] == '5' && line[c-2] == '5' && line[c-1] == '\n')) {
```

With some improvements:

```
void headerinfo(FILE *infile, FILE *outfile)
{
    char line[100];
    size_t c;

    do
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof line, infile);
        c = strlen(line);
        if (line[0] != '#')
            fputs(line, outfile);
    } while (! (4 <= c && strcmp(&line[c-4], "255\n") == 0));
}
```

Comment: If for any reason you would like me to delete my post, reply here or there, and I will.  I just found the output of the Linux `od` command that you suggested helpful, and thought others might also.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!

Comment: @EricPostpischil Using my code, is there a way to pull out the dimensions before the max color value and storing them into ints without seriously altering how the file is read in?

Comment: @AndrewZ: I do not know the specification of the PPM format. Your files have “P6” (a version ID?), a comment line, two dimensions, and “255” (a maximum pixel value?). To parse that, I would read the first line, verify it is a known version ID, then loop reading lines until one is not a comment line, then use `scanf` (with `%d`?) to read the dimensions, then read the next line (expecting it to be “255”). But there would have to be variations if the format were more flexible or other versions are to be supported. And I would use something more sophisticated than `scanf`, but it is a start.